# Can't get Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage to work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an existing WebAPI 2 project that was started from an empty project. There are several controllers, all using Attribute Routing. I followed directions to install the package and un-commented the required line in the HelpPageConfig.cs file. I then added the documentation to one of my controller's actions and tried to access it.

```
config.SetDocumentationProvider(new XmlDocumentationProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XmlDocument.xml")));
```

And I verified that the XML file is, indeed, in the App_Data folder.

Here is the piece of that controller:

```
   [RoutePrefix("Ssa")]
    public class SsaController : ApiController
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Session Statistics for a list of titles between two dates
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="TitleList"></param>
        /// <param name="StartDate"></param>
        /// <param name="EndDate"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Route("Title/{TitleList?}/{StartDate:datetime?}/{EndDate:datetime?}")]
        public IHttpActionResult getSsaGlobalTitles(string TitleList = null, DateTime?, StartDate = null, DateTime? EndDate = null)
```

When I request `http://myurl/help` I get a 404. `http://myurl/api/help` returns the "No HTTP resource was found" message. I seem to be not understanding something very basic. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi, under project properties and the build menu. Have you checked the checkbox for generating documentation? After that one is checked, you will get an XML file in your bin folder that is the documentation. Then you have to be sure that the path where you uncommented the lines to "enable" the help page documentation is pointing to that XML file. I placed the XML file in the App_Data folder. Sorry I am not being more specific, but do not have VS where I am at the moment.

Comment: @TeisLindemark, I checked and I do have App_Data specified and there is an XML file in there. There is not an XML file in my Bin folder, though.